# TensorFlow 2.2.0 : layer.Flatten don't work

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras

i have an np.matrix input of shape (11,19) and ma model is:

```
    inp2   = Input( shape=(11,19) )
    model2 = Dense( 19, activation="relu" )( inp2 )
    model2 = Dense( 10, activation="relu" )( model2 )
    model2 = Flatten()(model2)
    model2 = Dense( 10, activation="relu" )( model2 )
    model2 = Model( inp2,model2 )
```

and ia get the **error**:
Input 0 of layer dense_3 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 110 but received input with shape [11, 10]

**Where is my mistake?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `Dense( 10, activation="relu" )( model2 )` is already a flat tensor (ouput_shape = `(None, 10)`), no need to flatten it more.

Comment: okay thanks,
know i have an other question depending on this
as input i use  np.zeros((11,19))
and get the Error: WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 11, 19) for input Tensor("input_2:0", shape=(None, 11, 19), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (11, 19).

How can i fix this now?

Comment: @muellerelias What is the other question? I don't see it in the post

Comment: From what I see you are calling your model on one sample (shape (11, 19)) when you have to call it on list of samples (shape (n_samples, 11, 19)).
You can use numpy.reshape(input_array, (1, 11, 19))